# Customize icon for "Add to home screen"

Tags: html, icons, homescreen

Are there any alternatives to the default option in web browsers, like chrome that allows me to add a link or button in my webapp and create an icon in homescreen?

For example, I have my webapp and i want a link or button in the main.html that execute an script and create the icon in the homescreen. It is not possible i think. So are there any alternatives that simulate this default option in web browsers?

Also i want to specify the icon that shows in the homescreen. How can i do that?

Comment: You should specify the OS, the device(s) and maybe an example of what you want.

Comment: the OS are Android and IOS. And an example is like i describe it. Any button or link in my HTML that execute any script and create an icon in my homescreen. I search other post and it is not possible like this. I ask for maybe other alternatives.

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation. I changed it and i hope it is more helpful.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**I want to specify the icon that shows in the home screen. How can i do that?**

You can use `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="128x128" href="niceicon.png">` (yes, even for Android device).

Please check [iOS document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) for detail information on Apple devices. Please note you can even define icon for the entire website.

Please check [Android document](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen) for detail information on Android devices. If `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="128x128" href="niceicon.png">` does not work, you can try `<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="nice-highres.png">`, which is the recommended method in Android.

**Are there any alternatives that simulate this default option in web browsers?**

You can check http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen for an alternative. "add-to-home-screen" will show an overlaying message encouraging user to add the web app to the homescreen.

Note: Thanks to adam0404's comment, cubiq.org link is broken now. Fortunately, the "add-to-home-screen" library was uploaded to GitHub, please check https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen

Comment: one question. If i want to do this in both OS, i need to put also the both "link" tag? <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="128x128" href="niceicon.png"> this for IOS and <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="nice-highres.png"> this for Android in my "head" tag?

Comment: Normally, `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="128x128" href="niceicon.png">` is enough, as it is supported by Android (though not the recommended way). However, there are various Android devices and browsers in the market, some may not support it. My suggestion is: only use `apple-touch-icon` until you find it not work in some Android devices.

Comment: @shaochuancs cubiq.org link is broken

Comment: Thanks @adam0404, fortunately, cubiq.org's add-to-home-screen is uploaded to GitHub: https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen

Comment: thanks for the great answer.  this was so difficult to find anywhere.  so glad it's here.

Comment: Note: That link above to the Android docs is now 'stale' (broken). But, I managed to hack until I got something to work on Android. The secret seems to be that Android wants the 'rel' clause to be: rel="icon shortcut".  Additional observation: Before this tweak, I WAS getting a big black capital "F", for the home-scream, and I wondered why.  I later deduced (speculated) that it comes from the first letter of my  website's domain-name,.

Comment: @David, do you mind showing the working example? I have set rel="icon shortcut" but the add to home screen shotcut is still the capital letter instead of icon.

Answer (score 1):

First line apply to Web and Android, second line apply to iOS omit `sizes` tag to specify only one icon.

if jpg

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpeg" href="favicon.jpg">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="favicon.jpg">
```

if png

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="favicon.png">
```